# Is it possible to include models related to related models?

Tags: ember-cli-mirage

I have a model `Parent` that `hasMany('children')`. The `Child` model `belongsTo('uncle')`.

Is there a way to include `Uncle` in the `Parent` response using serializers? Right now I have custom responses in my server config, but I'd rather move it out.

Parent

```
import { Model, hasMany } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default Model.extend({
  children: hasMany('child'),
});
```

Child

```
import { Model, belongsTo } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default Model.extend({
  parent: belongsTo({ polymorphic: true }),
  uncle: belongsTo(),
});
```

Uncle is discovered from ember-data and has no defined relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You can either include the Uncle by default using a `child` serializer

```
// mirage/serializers/child.js
export default Serializer.extend({
  include: ['unclde']
});
```

or include it via the `?include` query param from the client

```
GET /parents/1?include=children.uncle
```

Comment: Is this because included models (`children` in this example) are serialized using their dedicated serializer?